# How to get Id of TextView on the front?

Tags: android, bringtofront

If I have layout like this, how to get the id of the `TextView` on the front after I use `bringToFront` on any of this `TextView`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text 3" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out.

Comment: tried it but `getChildAt(0)` will give id of first `textView` after bring `textView3` to the front. Not `textView3`.

Comment: `TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);` `tv3.bringToFront();`

Comment: try with `frameLayoutInstance.getChildAt(frameLayoutInstance.getChildCount() - 1).getId()`

Answer (score 2):

According to the implementation of `FrameLayout` `bringChildToFront`

```
public void bringChildToFront(View child) {
    int index = indexOfChild(child);
    if (index >= 0) {
        removeFromArray(index);
        addInArray(child, mChildrenCount);
        child.mParent = this;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

you should be able to retrieve the view you are looking for with

```
frameLayoutInstance.getChildAt(frameLayoutInstance.getChildCount() - 1).getId()
```